# Admin tabs for custom plugin

Tags: admin-menu

So I am new to WordPress plugin development, but I try to learn as fast as possible.
Basically, I try to create a tabbed navigation for my custom plugin.
What I've done so far, you ask?

- one function for displaying menu in left navbar

  ```
  function mb_menu_page()
  {
  add_menu_page('Big Name', 'Big Name', 'edit_posts', 'bigname', 'mb_big_name', false, 1);
  add_submenu_page('bigname', 'Link1', 'Link1', 'edit_posts', 'bigname',  'mb_big_name');
  add_submenu_page('bigname', 'Link2', 'Link2', 'edit_posts', 'bigname2', 'mb_big_name2');
  }
  ```
- add action

  ```
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mb_menu_page');
  ```
- Two new functions(page content)

  ```
  mb_big_name() && mb_big_name2()
  ```

Now, how can I get all links for this menu in order to parse them and create my tabbed  navigation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `admin_url()` function; it returns the admin URL with the first parameter appended, optionally:

```
admin_url( 'admin.php?page=bigname' );
```

Comment: I can't see how this can help me with my problem.
Anyway, I created a global array to use for admin menu and tabbed navigation.Thank you.

Comment: You asked how to get the links of the menu items you created and that's what I provided.

Comment: I need an array with all links(link1, link2) in order to parse it and create the HTML for tabs.

Comment: I trust you know how to create an array. Good luck with your project.